# Can I get NEXUS in California?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, california, nexus

I've seen this [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53925/is-nexus-clearly-better-than-global-entry-or-tsa-pre-check-for-us-citizens) that seems to indicate that Nexus is preferable to Global Entry. I live in California but I will travel to Canada next year.

Is it possible for me to get a NEXUS or is that limited to people near the border?

Comment: Have you deliberately chosen Nexus over Global Entry? Or do you just want whatever expedited border crossing solution you can get?

Comment: I saw the comparison chart and saw NEXUS as the cheapest, as well as it fitting my current situation. That being said I'm not dead set on Nexus. I guess from your logic Global Entry does the same job and is has places that are reasonably close for me to do an interview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

US or Canadian citizens or permanent residents [can get a NEXUS card](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/nexus-eligibility) regardless of where they live. But as part of the [process](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/how-apply), you must travel to a [NEXUS enrollment center](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/enrollment-centers) for an interview. Currently there are none in California or Nevada. Most of them, predictably, are near the northern border or in Canada.

Comment: Since I will be flying sometime to Canada, is it possible for to apply before my trip and go the interview in Canada or will that not work?

Comment: I don't see why not. But you may want to get the process started, as you can't schedule an appointment until after your application has been processed and you've been invited to do so.